# MSBuild with VS 2017 BuildTools set wrong $(VSInstallDir) at build time

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2017-build-tools

I am seeing some weird behavior with the latest 15.8.2 Visual Studio 2017 Build Tools. After installing the tools and ensuring that it has installed all workloads and components, I attempted to build our master solution from a batch file with the following command:

`msbuild %~dp0\..\..\Master.sln /verbosity:quiet /ds /p:Configuration=Debug;Platform=x64 /m /fl1 /fl2 /fl3 /flp1:LogFile="%~dp0\MSBuild.log";Verbosity=normal /flp2:LogFile="%~dp0\ProjectWarnings.log";WarningsOnly /flp3:LogFile="%~dp0\ProjectErrors.log";ErrorsOnly`

One of the very first projects fails with the following error:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\TextTemplating\Microsoft.TextTemplating.targets(340,5): error : System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\DAC\140\Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.dll'.`

If you'll notice, the path that can't be found is looking for the "Enterprise" directory, which obviously doesn't exist because we installed the Build Tools. The .dll in question is there in the correct directory, just under the "BuildTools" folder and not "Enterprise". In the project itself, we have this line for the above .dll:

`<HintPath>$(VSInstallDir)\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\DAC\140\Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.dll</HintPath>`

When looking at a developer command prompt on the system with just the Build Tools installed, running `set`, the variable `VSInstallDir` maps correctly to the BuildTools folder:

`VSINSTALLDIR=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\`

My question is this: where in the world is MSBuild getting the "Enterprise" directory from? We are not referencing it in ANY project, instead using $(VSInstallDir) when necessary. I have grepped the entire BuildTools directory for references to "Enterprise" and I'm finding nothing in .targets files or .props (or really any other files) that would indicate the variable would resolve to "Enterprise" rather than "BuildTools".

Comment: Could you please share the content of project file `.csproj` of the project you are having problems?

Comment: Since this is for a client, I do not have permission to post their source files to SO. What's the best way to send it to you privately?

Comment: Have you tried building with `/verbosity:diagnostic`? There could be some hints in the output.

Comment: That, I haven’t tried yet. We put this on the back burner to focus on other DevOps tasks, but I’ll be sure to post my findings here when I start this up in a few weeks.